# lazyload effect fadein not working with hyperlinks

Tags: fadein, lazy-loading

Using jquery 1.8.3, with http://www.appelsiini.net/2012/lazyload-180

effect:'fadeIn' no longer works on images that are hyperlinked?

If the image is just standalone the fadeIn works fine, but if wrapped in an anchor tag the image just appears without any effect.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: URL of the page you have problem with?